# C union for several structs and multiple structs

Tags: c

Hi I'm looking to build a union containing several structs and multiple structs. below is a brief example of what I want to achieve.

create union universe where galaxy and planet are structs...

```
union UNIVERSE{
    struct galaxy milkway;
    struct planet earth;
    struct planet mars;
    struct planet venus;
    int mega;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've already done exactly what you explained - what's the question?

Comment: Are you sure you know what a union is for?

Comment: So you are saying that your UNIVERSE is made up of only one of the following galaxy or planets, or an int?

Answer (score 4):

You've already done roughly what you seem to want, but I'd caution that what you seem to be trying to do doesn't make much sense.

In particular, earth, mars, and venus look a lot like they should be instances of a type. A union defines a type, so you probably want something like

```
typedef union { 
    galaxy g; 
    star s; 
    planet p; 
    nebula n;
} celestial_object;
```

Individual galaxies, planets, stars, etc., would be instances of that union. You could then have (for example):

```
#define max_objects 1000000

celestial_object universe[max_objects];

celestial_object earth;
earth.p.mass = 24;
earth.p.diameter = 12756;

celestial_object sun;
sun.s.mass = 30;
sun.s.diameter = 1400000;
```

...and so on.

Comment: This seems better, however, what I'd really like to achieve is something where my access looks like... 'code' universe.earth.mass = 24; universe.mars.mass = 22; 'code'. At the beginning of my code I know all the planets...